# Redux - Async - POST state on input field change

Tags: asynchronous, redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I have an application with some quite simple form fields and want on each update of a field to trigger a POST request to the server in order to get the data synced in the database.

On input field change a synchronous action is dispatched with the key & value of the field to be updated. This action is handled by the following reducer.

```
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case INPUT_FIELD_UPDATE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.key]: action.value
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Now I'd like to POST the whole new updated state to the server.

1. How can this be implemented using redux-saga/redux-thunk? Is it correct to trigger another action just after the above reducer has completed updating state? How can I trigger such action?

According response below, I'd update the state with new value and then POST data to server within the saga handler generator, but I'm not sure if this implementation is correct.
[How to fire AJAX calls in response to the state changes with Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262692/how-to-fire-ajax-calls-in-response-to-the-state-changes-with-redux)

2. Is it correct to POST the whole state and syncing it with the server on each change? Should only the new values be posted instead and update the app state on response?
3. Would you suggest a totally different approach?

*I'd like to clarify that after searching for quite some time now, I haven't found any clear answer in my question. New in the redux stack, I'm not quite sure how relevant my question may be.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation was much simpler than first thought. The only thing I had to do is to "hear" for the same dispatched action in my sagas.

```
function* handleChange(action) {
 try {
    let state = yield select(state => state);
    yield put(syncing());
    const response = yield call(api,{state});
    if(response.updated) {
       yield put(syncSucceeded());
    } else {
      yield put(syncFailed());
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(syncFailed(e));
  }
}

function* mySaga() {
   yield takeLatest(INPUT_FIELD_UPDATE, handleChange);
}
```